# Windows DTC Security Risks?

Tags: sql-server, msdtc, windows-security

I'm needing Windows DTC services enabled/configured to coordinate cross-server SQL transactions.  However, the network admin refuses my request because I need the following configuration setting:

[image]

I have scoured the web but unable to find documentation outlining security risks involved with enabling the 'No Authentication Required' flag.  Can anyone shed light on this configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in need of documentation for my question above, I was finally able to locate this after days of searching:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ajit/potential-risks-of-using-unsecure-rpc-no-authentication-required-setting-in-msdtc-security-configuration